# What actuator plates are compatible with the Duravit Durasystem In wall cistern?

Tags: electrical, plumbing, toilet

More specifically the WD1022000090 Durasystem Toilet In-Wall Tank & Carrier.

I have been looking at a couple including the Duravit branded one, but would rather go with a different actuator plate. I was considering the Geberit Sigma01 115.770.46.5 Toilet Actuator Plate and the Swiss Madison SM-WC001S Wall Mount Actuator Flush Push Button Plate In Chrome. Thanks

Comment: Have you asked the manufacturer?